# Actionscript 3 auto mouse click on XY stage coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is there any way to auto-click on XY stage coordinates upon when SWF is loaded?

EDIT: By the way, this is the whole code, and it is a cued youtube video. Just want to click anywhere on the cue to play it automatically after SWF loading.

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");


var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onError", onPlayerError);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onStateChange", onPlayerStateChange);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange", 
        onVideoPlaybackQualityChange);
}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {

    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);


    player = loader.content;

    player.setSize(300, 250);
    player.cueVideoById("AfTCtRDsWVw",0);
    player.mute();
}



function onPlayerError(event:Event):void {
    trace("player error:", Object(event).data);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
    trace("player state:", Object(event).data);
}

function onVideoPlaybackQualityChange(event:Event):void {
    trace("video quality:", Object(event).data);
}
```

Comment: what exactly you need to do? describe more please

Comment: I just added the whole code in the question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should just manually dispatch your MouseEvent.CLICK Event to your stage:

```
var yourX:Number = 40; //Whatever you want
var yourY:Number = 40; //Whatever you want
//Make sure you have a link to the stage (usually after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event occured)
stage.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
    MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    true, 
    false, 
    yourX,
    yourY);
```

If you need a certain DisplayObject to relate to this MouseEvent, you should pass an additional parameter to the MouseEvent constructor:

```
var yourX:Number = 40; //Whatever you want
var yourY:Number = 40; //Whatever you want
//Make sure you have a link to the stage (usually after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event occured)
stage.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(
    MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    true, 
    false, 
    yourX,
    yourY,
    linkToYourRelatedDisplayObject);
```

==UPDATE==

Well, I've made it. A bit of "hacking" and here it is.
Your youtube player contains a safeLoader object, which contains a videoApplication, which contains a LargePlayerButton. This LargePlayerButton has a MouseEvent.CLICK event listener, so we need to dispatch out event to this button instead of dispatching it to the stage.
Here's the complete code with autoClick simulation:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

// The player SWF file on www.youtube.com needs to communicate with your host
// SWF file. Your code must call Security.allowDomain() to allow this
// communication.
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

// This will hold the API player instance once it is initialized.
var player:Object;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));

function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader);
    loader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
}

function autoClick():void
{
    //=========================
    //Some nested children, we need to dig through a bit to get to the LargePlayButton
    var safeLoader:DisplayObjectContainer = (loader.content as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    var videoApplication:DisplayObjectContainer = safeLoader.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    var largePlayBtn:DisplayObjectContainer = videoApplication.getChildAt(6) as DisplayObjectContainer; 
    //=========================
    //And finally dispatching our event to this button. It will think that a person has clicked it
    largePlayBtn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
                                       true, 
                                       true, 
                                       stage.stageWidth / 2,
                                       stage.stageHeight / 2));

}

function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
    // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the Player API ID 
    trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);

    // Once this event has been dispatched by the player, we can use
    // cueVideoById, loadVideoById, cueVideoByUrl and loadVideoByUrl
    // to load a particular YouTube video.
    player = loader.content;
    // Set appropriate player dimensions for your application
    player.setSize(300, 250);
    player.cueVideoById("AfTCtRDsWVw",0);
    //====================================================
    //As long as player is loaded we can call our function
    autoClick();
}
```

It was a nice exercise, cheers :)

Comment: Neat, I had no idea that the MouseEvent constructor had that extra parameter (and so many more).

Comment: How should I incorporate this code to my code above? I can't seem to make it work.. Thanks!

Comment: @KumoKairo how should I incorporate this code to my code above?

Comment: @user2735161 unfortunately I don't work in Flash Pro IDE, but if you'll create a small demo project in a .zip folder, I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: @KumoKairo I've uploaded the small flash file and you may get it here
(http://tinyurl.com/ob2jyzt)

It contains FLA file of the project. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2735161 I've updated my answer :) It was easy, you should've just added one more line: player.playVideo();

Comment: @KumoKairo Thanks! But I noticed that the view count doesn't increase using playVideo() option.. Only if the cue was clicked then the view count will increase, so I think the best option is to apply the dispatchEvent to simulate the click

Comment: @KumoKairo do you have any email? I am willing to pay to get this autoclick done. playVideo() or loadVideo() is not an option. The only option is the mouse click option. I also have 2 different codes I got somewhere that does automatic mouse click action. I have limited knowledge in AS3 so I have to consult someone else to maybe incorporate these codes into the above code. Thanks!

Comment: @user2735161 I've already tried my auto-click method in your project but it doesn't seem to work, it's more complicated than just MouseEvent dispatching. I'll try it one more time tomorrow morning (I'm at UTC + 3.0), I think I know how to fix it, I just need a clear head. And I don't need money, thanks)

Comment: I appreciate it @KumoKairo ! I hope you can fix it

Comment: @KumoKairo the code above works like a charm in my machine but somehow when published through HTML or exported as SWF and uploaded to my server, its not functioning? I wonder what could be the reason.

Comment: @user2735161 I'm 99% sure your flash is not on focus upon loading. Do you embed it with SWFObject? If not, do so and it will most likely to solve this problem

Comment: @KumoKairo I tried embedding it with SWFObject but still no luck, I am guessing this has to do something with security sandbox?

Comment: @KumoKairo what puzzles me is that if your code is tested as "publish preview -> flash", it works like a charm without any human intervention. But when we choose "publish preview -> HTML" then it will not work, it only displays the cued video thumbnail and the autoclick function does not work. What is within that HTML preview option that prevents the click function to work?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube seems to have an intelligent anti hack feature. I'm able to get the children of SafeLoader on the IDE, but on the flash player, or the web, the SafeLoader just isn't accessible, and no children after that can be controlled. This is why the code works on the IDE but not outside. Maybe it has to do with sandbox security, but maybe it's more complex.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt very much that it is possible, for obvious security reasons : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is there any way to play the video automatically so the user won't have to click it first?

Comment: Never worked with youtube, but i guess you should use their api:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate this code into the code above to do the job? If yes, then how?


`function simulateClick(x:Number, y:Number):void{
    var e:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false, x, y)
    stage.dispatchEvent(e);
}`

Comment: @djib actually you can dispatch any user input events (mouse or keyboard events). User-initiated action requirements do not contain any restriction on mouse or keyboard events. They only forbid you to automatically copy something to clipboard, enter fullscreen mode and stuff.